# Playframework 2.6.2 runProd

Tags: sbt, production-environment, playframework-2.6

Im using Playframework 2.6.2 and I m trying to run in Production mode.
I tried command `runProd` after `sbt`
I have this error:

> (Starting server. Type Ctrl+D to exit logs, the server will remain in background)
>
> La ligne entrée est trop longue.
>
> La syntaxe de la commande n'est pas correcte.

I tried to put the project directly in C: but error maintains.

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

runProd is not valid on Play 2.6. The issue is caused by having a too long classpath, which is Windows specific.

Some options :

1) Run sbt stage, and execute the startup script in 
2) Put

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._
scriptClasspath := Seq("*")
```

on top of your build.sbt, and try again.

3) Use sbt-assembly to create on fat jar.